# Nest.js TypeORM - How to run same migration in different schema?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, database-migration, nestjs-typeorm

I am working on multi-tenant application where each tenant has different schema.

**example schemas:**

- public (default)
- tenant_001
- tenant_002

I am able to run migrations on `public` schema. But unable to run the migrations in other schemas

**Code**

```js
...
...
  const conn = await dataSource('default').initialize();
  // await conn.synchronize();
  await conn.runMigrations();

  const schemas = await conn.query(
    'select schema_name as name from information_schema.schemata;',
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < schemas.length; i += 1) {
    const { name: schema } = schemas[i];

    if (schema.startsWith('tenant_')) {
      const connection = await getTenantConnection(schema);
      // await connection.synchronize();
      await connection.runMigrations();
      await connection.destroy();
    }
  }
...
...
```

```js
export async function getTenantConnection(
  tenantId: string,
): Promise<DataSource> {
  const connectionManager = dataSource(tenantId);

  if (connectionManager.isInitialized) {
    return await connectionManager;
  }

  return await connectionManager.initialize();
}
```

```js
export const dataSource = (schemaName: string) => {
  if (schemaName === 'default' || schemaName === '') {
    return new DataSource(connectionConfig);
  } else {
    const newConnectionConfig = {
      ...connectionConfig,
      schema: schemaName,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      name: schemaName,
    };
    console.log({ newConnectionConfig });
    return new DataSource(newConnectionConfig);
  }
};
```

```js
const connectionConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE as any,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USR,
  password: process.env.DB_PWD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  logging: true,
  synchronize: true,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/**/*.migration{.ts,.js}'],
  name: 'default',
};
```

**Actual**

I can see only one table in those tenant schemas i.e `migrations`

**Expected**

All the migrations should run similarly to the `default` schema.

**Environment**

- masOS
- Postgres15 localhost
- NestJs
- TypeORM

Comment: Could you please provide more context for the `getTenantConnection` function? Also please validate that `schema.startsWith('tenant_')` matches something, because the example your provided states that schemas have no underscore in their names.

Comment: @Dezzley thanks for the reply. Yes, I have updated my questions with the `getTenantConnection` function. Also, there are typos in tenant001 it should be tenant_0001 & I have updated it also. Thanks!

Comment: do you manage to run the migrations for tenants using typeorm cli commands?